# Is there a way to sort outputs depending on a variable?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Im making a program that generates a song based on a random number generator. I have that down, but now I want to be able to control the outcome depending on a variable. Ex: variable1 = "eggs"; since variable1 is "eggs" instead of generating numbers 1-78, it only generates numbers 45-78.

```
import random

random_number = random.randint(1,56)

if unit == ('olive') or ('eggplant'):
  random_number = random.randint(4,8)
```

unit was an empty string, and when I ran this, it printed only the outputs connected to 4-8

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20002503/why-does-a-x-or-y-or-z-always-evaluate-to-true-how-can-i-compare-a-to-al

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax for the `or` statement is wrong.

You could do this, to properly use an `or` statement:

```
if (unit == 'olive') or (unit == 'olive'):
    pass # your code goes here instead
```

Or you could do this, to express the same idea with less cluttered syntax:

```
vegetables = ['olive', 'eggplant']
if unit in vegetables:
    pass # your code goes here instead
```